# Access 2016 - Password Protect Database

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-office, password-encryption

I'm new to Access programming. Is it possible to password-protect the database? I know I can go through "Set Database Password" to encrypt the database, however I don't wish to prompt the user to enter the password when opening the *.mdb. I wish to prompt the user only when they tries to access the database tables. Is this even possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Open Access 2016

**Step 2:** Click Open other files

**Step 3:** Click the DB you wish to encrypt and then instead of clicking open click the carat next to it. Now click open exclusive from the drop-down.

**Step 5:** After the Access  database file opens in Exclusive mode, click **File** then the **Info** tab and click **Encrypt with Password** button.

I know you are looking to avoid encrypting the ntire file itself but as far as I know this is the only way to encrypt the DB's

Comment: Thanks. I don't see a "Encrypt with Password" function, but "Set Database Password". Are you referring to this? But unfortunately, it's not what I'm looking for. I'm curious about "Manage Users & Permissions". How can we specify which user type are we logging in as?